# R tidyverse warning: The `i` argument of ``[`()` can't be a matrix as of tibble 3.0.0

Tags: r, tidyverse

I get a warning when wanting to select rows dependent on the mean of one of the variables in a tibble. See details below and warning. So I wonder if there is a more *tidyverse* solution to this.

Example data:

```
 x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
 y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
 z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

 xyz <- tibble(x, y, z)

 group1 <- xyz[xyz[2] < stats::median(purrr::as_vector(xyz$y), na.rm = TRUE), ]
```

Warning message:
The `i` argument of ``[`()` can't be a matrix as of tibble 3.0.0.
Convert to a vector.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xyz %>% 
  filter(y < stats::median(y))
```